# Is RegistrationId per device?

Tags: push-notification, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

I am implementing registration to Azure Notification Hub from my backend using [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn743807.aspx) as a guide. My applications will require authentication, but the user can logout and log back in with another account. Should the RegistrationId be based out of the unique device or the combination of user and device? In other words, should I clear the RegistrationId every time there is a logout? What about when the user logs out, logs back in as another user, but then logs back in as the original user, should we create a new RegistrationId or still use the original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GCM documentation for registering client apps](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration) states the following:

> Developers should never unregister the client app as a mechanism for logout or
> for switching between users, for the following reasons:
>
> - A registration token isn't associated with a particular logged in
>   user. If the client app unregisters and then re-registers, the app can
>   receive the same registration token or a different registration token.
> - Unregistration and re-registration may each take up to five minutes to
>   propagate. During this time messages may be rejected due to the
>   unregistered state, and messages may go to the wrong user.
>
> To make sure that messages go to the intended user:
>
> - The app server can maintain a mapping between the current user and the
>   registration token.
> - The client app can then check to ensure that
>   messages it receives match the logged in user.

This also applies to other push notification services, e.g. iOS.

A push notification service registration identifies a specific app on one single device.

With Azure Notification Hub, you can technically have multiple Azure Notification HUb registrations for a specific app on a single device and you could even register and unregister on login and logout (only at Azure Notification Hub, not on the plattform specific push notification system), but this would be error-prone and there is a better way:

- Register your app at Azure Notification Hubs as soon as you want to be able to receive push notifications and only unregister if you want to stop receiving them in general. Actually you can just register at app start and never unregister.
- If a user logs in, add a tag with the user ID (e.g. "user:123") to the registration and if he logs out, remove that tag again.
- This way, you can just use tags to address devices on which a certain user is logged in, see [Azure Notification Hubs Routing and Tag Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx).

Modifying tags is also describe in [the tutorial you linked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn743807.aspx).